# Display Last entry in first row in a browser

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a form in php with mysql.
When ever a user enter new data then that data automatically saved into database and also displays browser when i want. This form is for displaying mysql data in a browser.

All is working well. but what my problem is when a user submit data then that data displaying last one. but i need to display that details first in a browser.

```
<?PHP
    $connection=Mysql_connect('xxxresource.com','xxx','xxxx');
        if(!$connection)
        {
            echo 'connection is invalid';
        }
        else
        {
            Mysql_select_db('tions',$connection);

        }
//check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
  //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
  $startrow = 0;
//otherwise we take the value from the URL
} else {
  $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
}
    //this part goes after the checking of the $_GET var
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customer_details LIMIT $startrow, 10")or
die(mysql_error());
   $num=Mysql_num_rows($fetch);
        if($num>0)
        {
        echo "<table margin=auto width=999px border=1>";
        echo "<tr><td><b>ID</b></td><td><b>Name</b></td><td><b>Telephone</b></td><td>    <b>E-mail</b></td><td><b>Couttry Applying for</b></td><td><b>Visa-Category</b>    </td><td><b>Other Category</b></td><td><b>Passport No</b></td><td>        <b>Remarks</b></td></tr>";
        for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
        {
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($fetch);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo"<td>$row[0]</td>";
        echo"<td>$row[1]</td>";
        echo"<td>$row[2]</td>";
        echo"<td>$row[3]</td>";
        echo"<td>$row[4]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[5]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[6]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[7]</td>";
    echo"<td>$row[8]</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    }//for
    echo"</table>";
    }
//now this is the link..
echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+10).'"><img align=left     height=50px width=50px src="next.png"/></a>';

$prev = $startrow - 10;

//only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
if ($prev >= 0)
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'"><img align=right     height=50px width=50px src="previous.png"/></a>';
?>
```

My Problem is When a user submit data into mysql database then display that details first in a browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the most recent entry naturally be displayed first?

Comment: @ethrbunny, this is just what he wants...

Comment: @user2520162, don't use `mysql_...` functions in new code - use `mysqli_...` http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I guess I was (naively) assuming a 'last-first' sort.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM customer_details ORDER BY ? LIMIT $startrow, 10
```

Change `?` to whichever column you want to sort by.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: This is correct     SELECT * FROM customer_details ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $startrow, 10 Thanks to All